# Website files go on NAS or individual webservers?

Tags: networking

Playing with servers, first time with a NAS.

I have 2 servers I will use as web servers and 1 NAS.

Install OS and Apache on the 2 servers.

What is the rule for where website files go? On the NAS (so one place for website files and only one place to update) or on each individual web server (updates will have to be done on each server)?

I’m talking about files like framework files like Laravel or symfony, not images etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a bit opinionated but as a matter of convenience and flexibility, it would be better if your files are in the NAS. Why? Because as you indicated, updates will have to be done on each server if files are updated which can become a bottleneck. On the other hand, framework files and static assets do not really change that much so updating is not that hard.

Another scenario worth considering is that if you suddenly replace your web servers or add additional web servers, you do not need to worry about those files in the NAS.

Comment: Any reason they’d go on web server?

Comment: You mean what would be the advantage if you store the files on the web server?

Comment: Yes. What would be the advantage of files on webserver? I’m assuming it’d just be latency drop because it doesn’t have to go to NAS. Right?

Comment: You're right. That could be an issue but not really significant. W1, W2, and NAS are in one network right? Network latency shouldn't matter that much. Actually whatever gains you may get can easily get overridden once the need to update files across the web servers arises.